# Why are the initializations of my strings printed out?

Tags: c++, string, vector

Hello I'm doing a [challenge](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/30-review-loop) on Hackerrank. It is quite simple. The program takes in a number of strings and in the output I print the characters that are in the even index and the ones that are in the odd index of the string separated by a space. Here is my code:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int testCases;
    string word;
    cout << "Give number of test cases: ";
    cin >> testCases;
    vector<string> words;

    int i = 0;
    while (i <= testCases) {
        getline(cin, word);
        words.push_back(word);
        i++;
    }

    // Access each word and store the even values in the even string and odd values in odd string
    for (int j = 0; j < words.size(); ++j) {
        string newStr = words[j];
        string evenStr = "", oddStr = "";

        for (int k = 0; k < newStr.length(); ++k) {
            if (k % 2 == 0)
                evenStr += newStr[k];
            else
                oddStr += newStr[k];
        }
        cout << evenStr + ' ' + oddStr;
        cout << endl;
    }
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

For the example input of: `2` and the words `Hacker` and `Rank` I should get the output

```
Hce akr
Rn ak
```

But I get a newline before that that I don't want. When I initialize the `evenStr` and `oddStr` to `"a" I get as an output

```
a a
aHce aakr
aRn aak
```

My question is, why are the strings printed in the first place before I start concatenating them with the even and odd characters?

Comment: Why is the indention a mess? `while (i <= testCases) {` - Should this be a `for` loop?

Comment: @EdHeal here: `cin >> testCases;`

Comment: I have to agree with @Ed. Fixing the indentation probably clarifies where your logical error is.

Comment: I think the while loop is asking one too many.

Comment: And always use braces